# I can't find information on 2012 R2 Event ID's 257, 258, 265 Win32K errors

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-event-log

2012 R2 as a Hyper-V host only

Last night this machine began running very slowly.  I shut down the VM's and then the host.  That also took forever.

When I restarted the vm host machine it operated properly.  When I checked the vm host events I found these errors had occurred prior to the slowdown.  The sequence showed twice.

```
Event ID 265, Source Win32K, A pointer device did not report a valid unit of angular measurement
Event ID 257, Source Win32K, A pointer device reported a bad angular physical range
Event ID 258, Source Win32K, A pointer device reported a bad angular logical range
```

I'm not really finding any Microsoft pages that explain these errors and what needs to be done, if anything.

When I reboot this server these same errors show up twice again, a few minutes after booting up.

I wondered if anyone has some guidance regarding this set of errors.

Comment: I receive the same messages on a Windows 2012 virtual server.  Annoying as they are flooding the logs.  Even with the virtual pointer hardware disabled.

Comment: Same messages on fresh, fully updated 2012 R2 VM

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while remoting into a Hyper-V host over a VPN connection.

It seems to be an issue tied to the trackpad on my laptop and the RDP session configured to "use local resources" from my laptop (the trackpad).

Change your RDP session setting to disallow that and see what happens.